# Is there a list of aws resource prefixes?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm trying to figure out what pgw-xxxxxxxxx means but If there's a list that contains all of aws's resource prefixes maybe this answer would be much more useful to the stackoverflow community

Comment: "Is there a list?" borders on a request for an off-site resource, which would be off-topic, so we should probably stick with your actual problem for now.  I can think of igw, cgw, and vgw ... [internet | customer | virtual private ] gateway ... but pgw-xxxxxxxx doesn't spring to mind.  Where do you see this?

Comment: terraform was complaining about not having ownership of some pgw-xxxxxxxxx